# Dicom web viewer to save images which are uploaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am Using DICOM Web Viewer: open source zero footprint medical image viewer. How can I save uploaded dicom images into my local disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dwv, then, no, there is no way to save the uploaded images from dwv. It could be an interesting new functionality, you can add it to the dwv issues.

Comment: Yes I am Using dwv.Can you tell me how can I check and know the flow and also what is the use of download state button which onclick downloading state.json.Thank you

Comment: The state saves gui properties such as window/level, position, scale and offset. it also saves all the drawings. The flow would be for the user to load a DICOM file, do some manipulations and save the state. The next time he can load the DICOM file and the state to be in the same situation. State files can be loaded via drag and drop too. This could be improved, the flow could be made automatic to save manual steps...

Comment: Thanks for reply....I want to know How can I group objects on canvas and also is there a way can I use Fabric js in Dmv..